# Protégé 5.2: import Dublin Core elements ontology does not display 15 AnnotationProperty

Tags: ontology, protege, dublin-core

I am using Protégé desktop for windows.
I am importing the Dublin Core elements inside protégé with this URL: http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1

I was expecting to get access to the 15 AnnotationProperty, **dc:creator, dc:title, dc:contributor,...** but I can't see them.
Instead I am seeing some dcterms:title, dcterms:hasVersion,... (see the picture below)

[image: Dublin Core Annotation property after import]

Therefore, I am wondering what I am doing wrong.
Can I get the right procedure to do it well ?

Comment: These properties are not declared as Annotation Properties in the RDF file. Probably OWL API has some heuristics, but it seems they do not work in this case. Try to import [this](http://bloody-byte.net/rdf/dc_owl2dl/dc.ttl) OWL 2 DL version of DC Elements. See also some relevant explanations on [this](http://bloody-byte.net/rdf/dc_owl2dl/) page.

Comment: Hi Stanislav, whatever documents your comment was linking to, don't look like they're there any more.

Answer (score 3):

Thank to @StanislavKralin, I succeeded in importing the Dublin Core for OWL2 DL ontology.
Here is what he told me:

> These properties are not declared as Annotation Properties in the RDF file. Probably OWL API has some heuristics, but it seems they do not work in this case. 
>   Try to import [this](http://bloody-byte.net/rdf/dc_owl2dl/dc.ttl) OWL 2 DL version of DC Elements. See also some relevant explanations on [this](http://bloody-byte.net/rdf/dc_owl2dl/) page. – Stanislav Kralin Sep 21 at 15:41

Indeed, I can now get the 15 annotation properties.

Comment: I am unable to open both links

Comment: The links are not available now. I tried to import this namespace: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>, and get the dc:title and dc:pulisher in the annotation properties.

Answer (score 0):

The `dcterms` is simply a namespace abbreviation. As long as the full IRI of the property is the same, it does not matter if it is abbreviated to `dc:title` or `dcterms:title`. You can check the full IRI in Protege or by opening the ontology file as text - it will be XML with namespace declarations, see for example this fragment:

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#" xmlns:dcam="http://purl.org/dc/dcam/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">
    <dcterms:title xml:lang="en">DCMI Metadata Terms - other</dcterms:title>
```

Comment: @@Ignazio, the problem is not in prefixes. In short, the OP asks: where is `http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/subject`?!

Comment: The way I read the question, he's asking how to import the Dublin core ontology. The way he's doing it is correct, but he's getting confused by small syntactic differences.

Comment: Thank you for your feedbacks. I agree with @StanislavKralin. 
I want to know why the http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/subject is not visible in the Protégé editor as an annotation property.
I should get 15 property I only see 6 (see the screenshot in the question)